# Drools 7.7.0.Final generateModel fails with line and column information but no file information

Tags: maven, drools

I'm trying to build a kjar from our existing drools project with lots of individual rules file.
To speed up deployment I would like to generate the model into the kjar as introduced with Drools 7.7.0.Final.
The command I use is:  mvn clean install -DgenerateModel=WITHDRL -X

Pretty soon I get an error message:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.7.0.Final:generateModel (default-generateModel) on project foobar: Execution default-generateModel of goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:7.7.0.Final:generateModel failed: (line 1,col 33) Parse error. Found ",", expected one of  "%=" "&=" "*=" "++" "+=" "--" "-=" "/=" ";" "<<=" "=" ">>=" ">>>=" "^=" "|="
[ERROR] Problem stacktrace :
[ERROR]   org.drools.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.generateParseException(GeneratedJavaParser.java:11460)

There is no information in which file this error occured. Since our project contains >300 DRL Files it is a bit hard to find the culprit.

Is there any way to get more information out of the Drools Maven Plugin on which file is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's bug of kie-maven-plugin.
There are the bug's JIRA below.

[DROOLS-3505](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-3505)
[DROOLS-3523](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-3523)

If dialect is java and your rules have connect expressions with "comma" inside a modify block, The workaround is that
property inside modify block one by one.
the other workaround is changing dialect to mvel.
But, you have to write 'dialect "mvel"' in each rule file.
because dialect species isn't shared in package.